# How to store result from mysql query

Tags: c#, mysql

How do I store the results from a mysql query for use in other classes most efficiently?

I've tried the following code, which executes properly and stores all data in *reader* as it should. Reading the DataReader here works fine if I want to!

```
public class DatabaseHandler
{
    public void MySqlGetUserByName(string input_username, MySqlDataReader reader)
    {
        try
        {
            _database.Open();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '@input'";
            MySqlParameter param = new MySqlParameter(); param.ParameterName = "@input"; param.Value = input_username;
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, _database);
            command.Parameters.Add(param);
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            _database.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to read the same *DataReader* here, it is null and throws an exception (right after Debug6).

```
public class LoginHandler
{
    public static void UserAuth(Client user, string input_username, string input_password)
    {
        DatabaseHandler dataBase = new DatabaseHandler();
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = null; 
        dataBase.MySqlGetUserByName(input_username, dataReader);

        Console.WriteLine("Debug6");
        if (!dataReader.HasRows)
        {
            user.SendChatMessage("No match found.");
            return;
        }

        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            user.SetData("ID", (int)dataReader[0]);
            user.SetData("username", (string)dataReader[1]);
            user.SetData("email", (string)dataReader[2]);
            user.SetData("password", (string)dataReader[3]);
        }
        dataReader.Close();
    }
}
```

Please let me know how to make this work, or if there is a more efficient way of doing this without limiting the function of MySqlGetUserByName. The purpose of it is to input a name and a place to store all info from the match in the database.

Also, feel free to drop in any other suggestions that could make the code more efficient.

Comment: Most DB Objects ought to be created, used and disposed of in the scope thatr you need and use them.  So, dont (try to) return/'set' a DataReader.  Create a class to hold and transport the *data*.  These are called DTOs - data transfer objects - not unlike the Client/user object you already have.  Though that one seems a bit ragged with that SetData method in place of properties.

Comment: Passing a reference instance to a method, initializing it and expecting the calling code to see the new reference is a classic error in understanding how the references values are passed between methods. Your _reader_ in the called method is a different variable than the one you have in the calling method. It has, initially, the same value (null) but if you change that variable  to have a different value you are not changing the value in the caller method

Comment: Another error here is the parameter placeholder in your query. If you put the placeholder between single quotes it is no more a placeholder but simply a constant text and will not be used by the database engine.

Comment: Thank you @Steve! That really cleared things up for me! So the *reader* in the called method is merely a placeholder that tells the caller what type of value must be sent and which will be used in that method. It doesn't actually change the value in the caller method.

Comment: You should change the _MySqlGetUserByName_ to return a User instance and let the _UserAuth_ decide what to do if there is no user. The two methods are a classical example of the different concerns between a Data Layer and a Business Layer. The first should only care on how to retrieve data from the storage, the second should use the first to retrieve data and then decide what to do depending on your logic.

Comment: I get your point and the way you describe is what I'm trying to reach, however I can't understand how the called method should tell the caller that a user was found or not. I've updated the *MySqlGetUserByName* accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your MySqlGetUserByName to return a User instance if all goes well, otherwise you return a null instance to the caller (Or you can thrown an exception, or you can set a global error flag in the DatabaseHandler class..., but to keep things simple I choose to return a null)

```
public class DatabaseHandler
{
    public User MySqlGetUserByName(string input_username)
    {
        User result = null;
        try
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = @input";
            using(MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(......))
            using(MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, cnn))
            {
                cnn.Open();
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@input", input_username);
                using(MySqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                   if (dataReader.Read())
                   {
                       result = new User();
                       result.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader[0]);
                       ..... and so on with the other user properties ....
                   }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        // Return the user to the caller. If we have not found the user we return null
        return result;
    }
}
```

In the same way the caller handles the situation

```
public class LoginHandler
{
    public static void UserAuth(string input_username, string input_password)
    {
        DatabaseHandler dataBase = new DatabaseHandler();
        User result = dataBase.MySqlGetUserByName(input_username);

        // If we have not found the user we have a null in the variable 
        if(result == null)
        {
            // Send your message using a static method in the user class
            // User.SendMessage("User with username {input_username} not found!");
        }
        else
        {
            // User ok. return it? or do something with its data?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million! This looks really good. Not only did you provide the solution but you also made me understand what was done and why. Does `using(MySqlCommand....)` result in the removal of `dataBase.Close();`?

Comment: It seems like I still have to do `cnn.Open();` even though I'm now using `using(MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(......))` else it throws error: `System.InvalidOperationException: Connection must be valid and open.`

Comment: Yes, the using statement will dispose the connection object and in this process we have also a call to Close. So you don't need it anymore in your code. And yes you still need to open the connection. My bad, forgot about it.

Comment: @AdamEnderdal I suggest you to not change the original question. If someone reads this QA having a problem like yours they will not be able to understand most of our exchanges here. It is not a problem if your original question contains problems or errors. The whole point here is to understand the errors and how they could be fixed. If you want you can [edit] and rollback to the original text.

Comment: You're right, what was I thinking? Rolled back to initial question. Thanks again.